# How would weather and climate be different in a world that always receives sunlight from all sides?

Tags: science-based, climate, science-in-society

Consider a world in which instead of light coming from a single region of the sky, the sky appears close to uniformly luminescent.

The intensity of this light depends on latitude such that amount of radiation incident on any area at any time is around the average that would have been incident in that latitude on earth during daylight hours.

What differences would there by in climate and weather patterns on this planet as opposed to our own?

Comment: Quick question - your question says "Receives sunlight from all sides", but the content states "Sky appears to be uniformly luminescent". Receiving direct sunlight to all locations of the globe at the same time would required multiple stars as suggested in answers below, but is that what your question is asking? Other environment effects might be able to achieve the uniform luminescence without uniform heating.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason we have weather on earth is because earth has variable temperature. It may be 60 degrees in New York City and 80 degrees in Houston, and this causes pressure differential. Earth's surface is heated unevenly, and this heat attempts to redistribute itself across the globe. This redistribution causes air pressure to change, water to evaporate, etc. causing what we call, weather.

If this world received sunlight from all sides, the weather would be comparatively simple.

1.Humidity - If this world had enough water to support life, coupled with constant light from all sides, it would be very humid

2.Wind - This world would not have much wind. Since wind is the result of air moving from high pressure areas to low pressure areas, wind won't be common

3.Inclement weather - You could pretty much say goodbye to tornadoes, thunderstorms, and hail, as these are all caused when cold air and warm air collide. However, all of the air on your world will be the same temperature, so none of that

4.Climate - Specifically, the ocean. If this planet has oceans, they will have a ton of energy stored up, because they are constantly warmed on all sides. This will act like a giant heater to the land near the sea

5.Biodiversity - As the climate will be homogenous, animals will be fairly uniform throughout your world

These are only a few of the ways that a world like this would be different, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

### It would likely be more predictable at very least in the short term.

It would have weather still due to the fact that fluids like air moving around a rotating body like the planet itself, would inevitably develop areas of increased or decreased density for a variety of factors but the weather would probably be quite a bit more predictable overall.

The intensity or variety of these regions would probably vary based on what kind of gasses the atmosphere is made of.

Most importantly however, this planet is extremely dangerous because....

### It may have dangerous long term shifts in its global climate due to its orbit being eratic

In order to have truly equal amounts of light from all sides, such a world would likely need more than one light source.

If these light sources are stars, then keep in mind that the gravitational forces this planet is affected by will be extremely wild by the standards of what we have here on earth.

An orbit for this planet would therefore have a high likelihood of being pretty unstable due to the interactions of all of these celestial bodies.

One year it could end up closer, then suddenly farther away or even catapulted out of its home system as a [Rogue Planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_planet)

Regardless, due to its insane orbit, it would be likely be a very inhospitable place in the long term. Life would be very unlikely to survive on such a world.

Having multiple stars like this also practically garuntees that it will not have the same amount of light on all sides at one time.

### Your planet will have to be bend the rules of physics or use very advanced technology to distribute the light across its surface.

If you really want to have this kind of planet exist, you will have to bend physics with storytelling or technology.

For a technology idea, maybe your planet has a set of special mirrors around it to make sure it always gets good light distribution.